# How to combine two or more relocatable ELF files into one relocatable ELF file using GNU ld?

Tags: c, assembly, ld, elf

I have two x86 assembly source files a.asm and b.asm (written in NASM syntax).

a.asm and b.asm combined is an implementation of the function myfun(int a, int b) which returns a+1+b. But I put the codes into separate files.

```
; a.asm
global myfun

myfun:
   push ebp
   mov  ebp,esp

   mov eax, [ebp+8]
   inc eax
```

the second file b.asm contains the rest instructions for myfun

```
   ; b.asm
   add eax, [ebp+12]
   pop ebp
   ret
```

Then I used nasm -f elf32 to compile a.asm and b.asm, and get a.o and b.o.
After that I combined a.o and b.o using the following link script to get c.o

```
SECTIONS {

    .text : {

      a.o (.text)

      b.o (.text)

     }

}
```

The function can be called from a C file and returns correct result.

My question is:

1. file c.o shows that c.o is executable with a program header, although the function myfun in c.o can be used at link time. How to make c.o a pure relocatable file without a program header?
2. there are junk instructions (nopw) inserted between a.o (.text) and b.o (.text) in c.o to make it 16-byte aligned (b.o (.text) is started at 16-byte boundary in c.o). Can I add some link script command to make  a.o (.text) and b.o (.text) compactly combined so the machine codes in c.o (.text) is just like codes compiled from c.asm where c.asm is obtained using command:

   cat a.asm b.asm > c.asm

Comment: Ah, one of these four-eye nuclear launch codes....

Comment: I know very little about link script and ELF format. This is just an exercise for me to learn how to use link script to control the linking process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I am not sure what the point is, here are your answers:

1. If I understand you correctly, you want to do incremental linking. Use `-i` or `-r` switch to `ld`.
2. You can set the section alignment either in the assembly source by using `SECTION .text ALIGN=1` or in the linker script by using `SUBALIGN(1)`

Comment: Thank you very much, Jester. This is just an exercise, otherwise this is no point doing thing like such.

Comment: Another question is Can I change the output of ld from executable type to a relocatable ELF. The default output type is executable ELF.

Comment: use `-r` to create relocatable elf files